# How do I use multiple values from the same column in the WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a table that holds the region information. The regions are as follows:

- Statewide - 2 results
- North - 4 results
- South - 4 results
- East - 3 results
- West - 7 results

Currently, when a user selects Statewide, they get the result from Statewide. But logically it would make more sense if the results were displayed from all the other regions as well because they are a part of the state. Currently, it is only showing **2 results** but it should show **20 results**

Also, if someone selects East they should see the results from the name of the Region + Statewide. So if someone selects East, the result should be from East + Statewide. It is currently showing **3 Results** instead of **5 Results**

Can someone please help me with this? Your help will be much appreciated.

I have tried AND, OR, XOR and UNION statements but none of them seems to work.

```
if (!empty($region_name)) {

            if($region_name !== 'Statewide'){
                $venueArray[] = " AND (REGION = '$region_name' ) XOR ( REGION = '$statewide')";
            }else if($region_name == 'Statewide'){
                $venueArray[] = " AND (REGION = '$region_name' ) XOR ( REGION != '$statewide')";
            } else{
                $venueArray[] = " AND (REGION = '$region_name')";
            }

        }
```

Lines 1 - 10 /search.php

Comment: this `if/else` statement is already illogical, because the `else` branch is unreachable... while most likely the region is also irrelevant, when searching state-wide. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html

Comment: Edit your question and add the SQL statement, it may be possible to get the data selected the way you want there. Couldn't you just use a where clause like ```WHERE REGION IN ('statewide', 'east')``` ?

Comment: @SloanThrasher as stated, this is illogical, because state-wide covers all regions... possibly difficult to tell without sample data to verify the claim, but it appears quite alike.

Comment: @MartinZeitler: Check the 3rd paragraph of the OP's question. ```if someone selects East they should see the results from the name of the Region + Statewide```

Comment: @SloanThrasher this requirement sounds just as illogical as the `if/else` condition... I mean, "if someone selects east" - they should get displayed the east (else one can get rid of the filter-condition altogether). so why one should include the north, south and west ...when selecting the east?

Comment: @MartinZeitler: If I understand the OP correctly, Statewide is a "region" in addition to North, South, East, West.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the region name is `Statewide` you want **all** results (so no condition is necessary), otherwise you want the region and the `Statewide` results, so your `if` can be simplified to:

```
if (!empty($region_name) && $region_name !== 'Statewide'){
    $venueArray[] = " AND (REGION = '$region_name' OR REGION = '$statewide')";
}
```

Note the change in brackets to ensure this condition plays well with other ones in terms of operator precedence.

Comment: Thanks for your help Nick, the code seems to have worked for me. I realised the logical flaw in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am not much aware about the php, So I am providing you the solution in SQL query, which may help your result.

```
Declare @region_name varchar(20)
set @region_name = 'North'  /*You can pas any state here*/

Select * 
from tbl_region
Where (
   (@region_name = 'StateWide' And 1=1)   /*it selects all record in the table*/
     And 
   (region_name = @region_name or region_name = 'Statewide') /*it retrieves records for passed region name and statewide*/
  )
```